# Storing real-time time-series data in GridDB with automatic row expiry and cache size configuration?

Tags: sql, griddb

I'm trying to build a real-time data processing system using GridDB, I want know how  to store large columes of time-series with automatic row expiary and configurable cache size

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    sensor_value DOUBLE
) WITH ROW EXPIRATION TIME '10m' AND CACHE SIZE '10000';
```